# Cypress send multiple requests and doesn't allow to login

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am using `Cypress 4.3.0` version, the baseUrl = "https://tenant-demo.somesitedev.net" has been set in cypress.json file. While I am sending the `cy.request()` command, it is sending multiple request (please see Fig:1) . Also, when I observed the visit command I could see following Original Url, Resolved Url and Redirects. In this scenario, how do I login to the site using `cy.request()` command.

```
before(()=>{
    cy.visit('/').then(()=>{
        cy.get('input[type="hidden"]').invoke('val').then((val)=>{
                const token = val;
                cy.login(token);
        }) 
     })

    }) 

Cypress.Commands.add('login', (token) => {
    const username= 'test1.user';
    const password= 'somepassword';
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('tokens');
    const cookieValue = document.cookie.split(';');
    const configCat = localStorage.getItem('ConfigCat_');
  cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/dashboard',
      failOnStatusCode: false,
      form: true,
      body:{
        _token: token,
        username,
        password
      },
      headers: {
        'accept': 'text/html',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'authorization': `bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'ConfigCat_': `${configCat}`,
        'cookie': `${cookieValue}`
       }
     }).then((res)=>{
      visitDashboard();
     })
  })

  const visitDashboard = () => {
    cy.visit('dashboard')
  }
```

**Fig:1**

[image]

**Fig:2**

[image]

Comment: Can anyone advise some suggestion on how to resolve the above question ?

Comment: I have posted my ans below if someone need to look or experience the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to find a way to resolve the problem. Since the `baseUrl` has got some path extension `/auth/login`, whenever I trigger a cy.request() it was always redirecting back to login page even though the credentials was correct. Also there were two requests in the console.

So the way I did was to send another `cy.request()` with GET method with `body` params immediately after the first POST cy.request() with `qs` parameters. From the request headers I find out there was a 'token' submitted every time when the user login.
If there is another easy way let me know.

Cypress version : 4.4.0

Inside `beforeEach()`, grab the 'token' value;

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.loadTokens();
    cy.get('input[name="_token"]').invoke('val').then((val)=>{
        const tokenValue = val;
        cy.loginRequest(tokenValue);
      })
    })
```

Following is the `commands.js` file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('loginRequest', function (tokenValue) {
     return cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: Cypress.config('baseUrl'),
      followRedirect: true,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
      },
      qs:{
        _token: tokenValue,
        username: 'your_username',
        password:'your_password'
      }
    }).then(()=>{
      return cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://tenant-demo.somesitedev.net/dashboard',
        followRedirect: false,
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body:{
          _token: tokenValue,
          username: 'your_username',
          password:'your_password'
        }
      })
    })
  });
```